# Python: Should a new RangeError exception be derived from the Exception class or from the ValueError class?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I'd like to create a new exception for my Python module: RangeError. I would return this error when a value is out of an expected range.

My question is: should I derive the new error from the Exception class (as is suggested by the Python documentation) or should I derive it from the ValueError class (which makes more sense to me)?

What are the benefits and downsides to one option or the other? Will I be crippling future development if I derive it from the ValueError class?

(Note that this would not be for index out-of-range, as that's already handled by IndexError.)

Thanks,

Comment: It makes no difference .... I always just inherit custom exceptions from Exception ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `RangeError` inherits from `ValueError`, then you will be able to catch it by catching `ValueError`:

```
>>> class RangeError(ValueError):
...     pass
...
>>> try:
...     raise RangeError
... except ValueError:
...     print("handler for ValueError")
...
handler for ValueError
>>>
>>> try:
...     raise RangeError
... except ValueError:
...     print("handler for ValueError")
... except RangeError:  # Ignored because except ValueError: was reached first
...     print("handler for RangeError")
...
handler for ValueError
>>>
```

Therefore, you should only inherit from `ValueError` if:

1. `RangeError` is meant to be a specific kind of `ValueError`.  In other words, it is a further classification of the latter just as `ZeroDivisionError` is for `ArithmeticError`.
2. You want people to be able to catch `RangeError` by catching `ValueError`.

Otherwise, you should inherit from `Exception` because:

1. `RangeError` is **not** a specific kind of `ValueError`.
2. `RangeError` should **not** be caught by catching `ValueError`.  Instead, users should explicitly handle it by `except RangeError:`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for: people able to catch RangeError by catching ValueError. I think that will make my modules easier to use. Thanks!